# Gridseed USB ASIC Won't Mine Bitcoins

Tags: cgminer, asic, bfgminer, gridseed

Okay so I have done my research, I have practically tried everything. It just frustrates me because mining LTC was a piece of cake but I can't seem to figure out how to mine bitcoins which this device says it can do bitcoins plus dual mining.

I have tried BFGminer but it seems not to detect my gridseed unless I am mining LTC. Then I tried CPUMiner and it works except it gets invalid all the time its like its using the wrong algorithm but I tried the -a sha256d and still produces the same issue. Can somebody help me I have the drivers installed and my usb Gridseed miner is on COM6. I have also tried CGMiner and it says cannot detect any USB devices.

I have tried every possible thing that comes up on the first few Google Results. I am not exactly new to mining as I have done Scrypt mining fine with this device.

[Here is the product.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J4XPKJU)

Comment: Is there any sort of an error message printed when you try to mine, or are your shares rejected?

Comment: For cpuminer it just rejects shares, I am not talking a few but all of them. For BFGMiner it doesn't detect it but I think BFGMiner doesn't support Gridseeds for mining BTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [link](http://www.overclock.net/t/1487157/gridseed-help) apparently cgminer doesn't like usb3 according to the forum post don't know why I thought usb3 is backwards compatiable. But I tried thinking this is bull but it worked.